# Regarding drivers for windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, drivers

I have gygabyte motherboard and i am planing to install on it windows 2008 r2 server this mother board dont have drivers for windows 2008 r2 only for windows 7 and windows 8. Can i use drivers for windows 7 or windows 8 and wich one are closest to windows 2008 r2 for compatibility ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use windows 7 drivers.  For **most** purposes, Server 2008 R2 is equivalent to 7, 2012 ~ 8.0, and 2012R2 ~ 8.1

However, if they don't have server drivers that means it's not a server motherboard.  Hopefully what you're setting up isn't mission critical or you have a lot of redundancy.